# .htaccess does not redirects to custom 404 page

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm currently working on my own website which runs on an local Apache Server.
I have a *.htaccess* file which is supposed to redirect 404 errors to a custom page.
Here it is:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

But all I get is the following error instead of my custom 404 page:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /my-site/gqehgr was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to 
use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

I saw on several forums that I could use the RewriteEngine but I don't understand how it works.
Does anybody have a clue?

**EDIT:**
The line should be:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /my-site/404.php
```

Comment: Is the path correct to your php file?

Comment: Yes. The 404.php file is in the same folder as .htaccess which is the root of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `404.php` can not be found. Check your files. Try to request `/404.php` manually.

Comment: I knew that but why it cannot find it? That is my question.

Comment: Maybe it's located in `/my-site/404.php`, not in `/404.php` ?